# using depends with max - jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, max

I need to add a conditional max value on a field using `jQuery validation`. I learned about `depends` but somehow I think the validate is not working.

This is the block of code. The `dropdown` selection is working properly. I had placed an `alert` and it gives the desired value. However, the `max` validation doesn't work.

```
rules: {
   txtFirstName: { required: true,
     max: { depends: function (element) {
              var dropdown1 = $("#ddl option elected").val();
              if (dropdown1 == "C") {
                 return 100;
              }
              else {
                 return 200;
              }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think `depends:` is just a used to determine whether to apply the rule, not to supply parameters to the rule.

Comment: Barmar is correct.  You cannot return a parameter.  Also, `max` is looking for numerical input.  Maybe you wanted `maxlength`?

Answer (score 2):

@Spanky answer is correct. but inorder for it to work, You need to add `param`

```
        max: {
            param: 6.2 // Max value
            depends: function (element) {
                return if(10>2); //Condition
            }
        }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pf6tpamp/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a parameter using the `depends` method.

Here's a quick test that shows how `200` is interpreted as a boolean `true`...

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        txtFirstName: {
            required: true,
            max: {
                depends: function (element) {
                    return 200;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pf6tpamp/

The `depends` method is for rules that can only be declared with a boolean `true` and no parameters.

(Also, `max` is looking for numerical input.  Maybe you wanted `maxlength`?)

Comment: i tried to modify ur fiddle a bit. Bit it is working weirdly.[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pf6tpamp/2/)

Comment: Of course it's not working.  My answer is that you cannot use `depends` like that.

Comment: is there a way i can do it? i tried this as well. not working.[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pf6tpamp/4/)

Comment: Use `addMethod` to create a custom rule.